# R: fast table lookup with ifelse vectorization

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to use a table-lookup to speed up some but not other calculations.  For example, for the normal distribution cdf:

```
cdf <- pnorm

BINS <- 10
MINZ <- (-5)
MAXZ <- 5

cdftbl <- rep(NA, BINS+2)

xi <- 0; SSZ <- (MAXZ-MINZ)/BINS
while (xi<=BINS+2) {
    x <- MINZ+xi*SSZ
    cdftbl[xi+1] <- pnorm(x, log=TRUE)
    xi <- xi+1
}

fastlogcdf <- function( x, m=0, sd=1 ) {
    z <- (x-m)/sd
    zi <- (z-MINZ)/(MAXZ-MINZ) * BINS
    zi.whole <- as.integer(zi)
    zi.frac <- zi-zi.whole
    zi.index <- zi.whole+1
    zi.tindex <- pmax(1,zi.index)  ## will not throw an array index error!
    ifelse( (zi.index <= 0) | ((zi.index+1) >= BINS),
       pnorm(x,m,sd,log=TRUE),
       cdftbl[ zi.index ]+zi.frac*(cdftbl[ zi.index+1 ]-cdftbl[ zi.index ]))    }
```

this works (badly) well with

```
   fastlogcdf( seq(-2,2,0.5))
```

but not with

```
   fastlogcdf( seq(-8,8,0.5))
```

because the `ifelse` wants to evaluate the two outcomes completely before it assigns based on the condition.  usually, I can ignore this, but this produces an intermediate error that  *only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts* . of course, there is no `cdftable[-8+1]`.

one way is to use the tindex that I have defined, but it seems strange to map to some random useless number in the vector first and then discard it.

alas, even this solution still does not solve the problem, because the whole point is to avoid the slow pnorm() call when the table lookup will do!  So I really do need a true conditional ifelse that only evalutes the true statement side for each vector element.

what is the R way of solving this little dilemma?  advice appreciated.

regards, /iaw

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I didn't feel I could fit this in a comment, sorry:

Based on your function, and how you've called it, m=0 and sd=1, that means z will always equal x. So whenever x is outside the MINZ to MAXZ range, your expression:

```
(z<=MINZ)|(z>=MAXZ) returns TRUE
```

In your first sequence (-2 : 2), you never encounter this (it always equals FALSE), but in your second (-8 : 8) you do. So that's the only time you're calling

```
cdf(x,m,sd,log=TRUE)
```

Your problem is most likely there. I don't know what that function is, have you defined it yourself?

Comment: yes, it is that it exceeds the array.  one way to solve this would be to put another ifelse into the array index, but this is another condition and ugly.  I clarified what cdf is (i.e., pnorm).